# Why does $a>b$ imply $(a-b)/2 > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Sorry if this is an easy explanation but I'm having trouble understanding why $a > b$ implies that $(a-b)/2 > 0$. I'm trying to understand this theorem and its proof:

$a<b+\epsilon$ for all $ϵ>0$ implies $a\leq b$

I understand that the best way to go about it is to prove by contradiction. So you would assume $a > b$. From the other proofs I've seen it says that $a>b$ implies $(a-b)/2 > 0$.

I tried reorganizing it, but don't understand where the divide by $2$ comes from.

Sorry if this has been asked before or if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: $a>b$ implies $a-b>0$, implies $\frac{1}{2}(a-b)>0$.

Comment: Because if $a > b$, then $(a-b)$ is positive.

Comment: Other than MathJax this question meets quality standards for the site.  Try not to confuse "low-quality" with "easy". (+1)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I get the a>b implies a-b > 0, but where does the 1/2 come from?

Comment: If $a>0$, then $ra>0$ for every $r>0$. So it comes from $r=1/2$.

Comment: If $a > b$, then $a - b > 0$. Thus, $0.5 (a - b) > 0$ or $(a-b)/2 > 0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde is there any reason to why r = 1/2 for this implication? Why can't it be a different number?

Comment: It can be any other $r>0$, but look at your title. You didn't ask for $(a-b)/5>0$, but rather for $(a-b)/2>0$.

Comment: This may not be your particular confusion, but it's noteworthy that in mathematics, "implies" does not mean "naturally leads to." It simply means that if the first thing is true, the second thing is also true. I might also say that if $n$ is a perfect square, then $n > -7$. There's no particular reason I would want to say that, necessarily, but it's still true.

Comment: @BrianTung Ah I see, thank you for clearing that up/

Comment: For the result mentioned in question, the key idea to obtain a contradiction is by choosing a value of $\epsilon >0$ which is less than $a-b$. The author has taken $(a-b) /2$ as a suitable value of $\epsilon $. You can more generally say "let us choose an $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon <a-b$" and then you automatically get $a>b+\epsilon $ and a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Let consider the following chain of implications

$$a>b \implies a-b>b-b \implies a-b>0 \implies \frac{a-b}2>\frac 02 \implies \frac{a-b}2>0$$

that is

$$a>b \implies \frac{a-b}2>0$$

Note also that in the same way we can prove that the reverse is also true $\frac{a-b}2>0 \implies a>b$ that is

$$a>b \iff \frac{a-b}2>0$$

Moreover, as noticed in the comments, for any $n>0$ we can show in the same way that

$$a>b \iff \frac{a-b}n>0$$

---

The proof for the particular theorem you are referring to:

- $a<b+\epsilon$ for all $ϵ>0$ implies $a\leq b$

should be as follows:

- let assume by contradiction $a>b$
- then for any $n>0$ we have $\frac{a-b}n>0$ and therefore exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that

$$0<\frac{\varepsilon}n\le\frac{a-b}n \implies a-b\ge \varepsilon \implies a\ge b+\varepsilon$$

---

As an alternative, we can proceed by a direct proof by exhaustion, that is:

- $a=b \implies a-b=0<\varepsilon \implies a-b<\varepsilon  $, $\forall \varepsilon>0$
- $a<b \implies a-b<0 <\varepsilon \implies a-b<\varepsilon  $, $\forall \varepsilon>0$
- $a>b$ let assume $\varepsilon =\frac{a-b}2>0$ then $a-b>\varepsilon$

therefore

$$a<b+\varepsilon, \:  \forall \varepsilon>0 \implies a=b \lor a<b$$

Comment: For that particular theorem I posted in my question, a<b+ϵ for all ϵ>0 implies a≤b, is there a particular reason as to why n is set to 2 for the proofs I've seen.

Comment: @reclaimer2 I've indicated the reason to justify the implication and there is no reason to take $n=2$ since any $n>0$ works fine. For the particular theorem, maybe it would be useful add some more detail on the full proof.

Comment: Anyway, since the theorem refers to any $\epsilon >0$ there is no reason to take $n=2$ or any other value since we can always set $\varepsilon=\varepsilon_n$ such that $0<\varepsilon_n<\frac{a-b}n$.